# Как назначить цвет рамки каждой ячейки таблицы?

Tags: html

Я прохожу курс основ фронтенда, поэтому у меня много, наверно, абсолютно глупых вопросов. В общем, на этот раз я не знаю, как в таблице назначить рамку и цвет для каждой ячейки отдельно. Как на рисунке. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так а в чем трудность? Идентифицируешь каждую ячейку (например, `<td id="cell1">...</td>`), затем задаешь ей стили: (например: `#cell1 { border: 5px solid #f00; }`)

Comment: class правильнее будет нежели id

Comment: Псевдокласс [:nth-child](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child) и иже с ним

Comment: о, черт, спасибо!

Comment: моя ошибка была в том, что я писала 
border: 2 px solid red; и на "текстовый" цвет оно не реагировало
спасибо!

Comment: @quaresma89, неужели?

Comment: @Ingrid, не на текстовый цвет. пробел между `2` и `px` не нужен.

Comment: @quaresma89,надо будет покрасить 4 ячейки одинаковым цветом,интересно каким образом вы навесите один и тот же айди на 4 ячейки и зададите им стиль? Не проще ли создать один класс и присвоить его?

Comment: @quaresma89, вы говорите, что классы использовать правильнее а я не понимаю, в чем, по-вашему, заключается "правильность". может я хочу якорную ссылку сделать к этой ячейке или напрямую обратиться из JavaScript. нигде же не сказано, что у нас множество таких ячеек.

Comment: Зачем углубляться и создавать задачу которая не относится к теме,я написал что по теме вопроса использовать классы будет более гибким решением нежели айди.Делайте себе якорные ссылки,как вам класс будет мешать при этом ?)

Comment: Есть хороший сайт http://www.w3schools.com/ там достаточно хорошо обьясняются многие моменты

Answer (score 1):

```css
table{
    width:100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
    background: #FEF834;
    border: 2px solid #17152B;
}
table td{
    border: 2px solid #BCB946;
    padding: 15px;
}
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1){
    border-color: #ED4630;
    background: #fff;
}
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2){
    border-color: #222200;    
}
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3){
    border-color: #2242E3;  
    background: #6CF8FC;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1){
    border-color: #FFFEF1;
    background: #E964FE;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2){
    border-color: #B23322;
    background: #EC52A1;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3){
    border-color: #A161B9;
    background: #ACB02D;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td> 
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>    
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете применить отдельные стили для каждого элемента вашей таблицы. Например так:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset=utf-8">
  <title>Рамка</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th style="border:2em solid #2f4f4f">Firstname</th>
    <th style="border:2em solid #228b22">Lastname</th> 
    <th style="border:2em solid #ffa500">Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:2em solid #0000cd">Eve</td>
    <td style="border:2em solid #006400">Jackson</td>
    <td style="border:2em solid #ffff00">94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**[Документация W3](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)** + **[цвета ХТМЛ](http://www.stm.dp.ua/web-design/color-html.php)**. Эта техника рекомендуется валидатором скорости Гугл. Так сканер быстрее загружает видимую часть страницы.